# How to replace Master Branch files with Develop Branch on remote?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have an out dated Master Branch contains committed files with unresolved conflicts, and i have a Develop Branch that contains the latest code with no problem.

How can I replace my master branch files with files in develop branch?

Please advise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to just wipe out what you have on `master` and make it be identical to `develop`...

`reset` your `master` branch to point to the same commit as `develop`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard develop
git push -f origin master
```